# Async Task doInBackground Only Being Called Once

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am POST-ing the current location of my phone with the press of a button to a local webserver. The webserver receives the POSTs correctly.

However, for some reason, I can only send one location to the server, and after that the [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is only called once. **EDIT: The Async Task is called, but the doInBackground method is not called.** - then with each subsequent button press the task is not reached. I did read in the above link that it can only be called once, but I assume that's only once per object - and for some reason, this was all working just fine before I changed something and it's all screwed up.

I need to be able to send hundreds of these requests within the period of a few minutes from the phone, so any guidance here would be useful. Thanks!

```
package com.spencer.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    LocationManager mlocManager = null;
    LocationListener mlocListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               getAndSendLocation();
            }
        });

        /*new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getAndSendLocation();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, 1000);*/
    }

    public void getAndSendLocation() {

        final TextView latitudeField = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.lat);
        final TextView longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longit);

        if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            latitudeField.setText("Latitude: " + MyLocationListener.latitude + '\n');
            longitudeField.setText("Longitude: " + MyLocationListener.longitude + '\n');

            new doPost().execute(MyLocationListener.latitude, MyLocationListener.longitude);

        } else {
            latitudeField.setText("GPS is not turned on...");
            longitudeField.setText("GPS is not turned on...");
        }
    }



    public class doPost extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            double lat = (Double) objects[0];
            double longit = (Double) objects[1];

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.110:3000/coord");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", Double.toString(lat)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", Double.toString(longit)));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }
}
```

Comment: use a service with alarammanager. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html. check the topic More on services

Comment: You can use a Flag and based on flag value call the asynctask with the relevant value being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AsyncTask.execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29)

As per doc:

> Note: this function schedules the task on a queue for a single background thread or pool of threads depending on the platform version. When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting HONEYCOMB, tasks are back to being executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution. If you truly want parallel execution, you can use the executeOnExecutor(Executor, Params...) version of this method with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR; however, see commentary there for warnings on its use.

So, you should call like this:

```
 new doPost(). executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask. THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR , MyLocationListener.latitude, MyLocationListener.longitude);
```

This would execute all threads in parallel, also keep an API 11 check on this method.

Hope that helps. :)